# How to set a default value in AssociationField EasyAdmin 3

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin3

I'm starting with EasyAdmin v3.
I want to set a default value in easyAdmin.
In php/symfony i would provide:

```php
$article = new Article::class;
$article->setAuthor($user)
```

Before creating the form to set the currentUser in my entity but with EA3 i don't know how to manage this.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override methods like `createEntity()`:

```
class ArticleCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Article::class;
    }

    public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
    {
        $article = new Article();
        $article->setAuthor($this->getUser())

        return $article;
    }

    // ...
}
```

See [this part of the documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/crud.html#creating-persisting-and-deleting-entities) for more information.