# EasyAdmin 3 how to set association from action createEntity based on query

Tags: easyadmin3

I wish to create add an action that goes to the new action but pre-populates the entity based on added url parameters.  For example to set an association.

The documentation shows how to override the createEntity method the set values, but this method has no way to get the parameters from the request so I cannot set the association based on a passed parameter.

This is similar to [How to set a default value in AssociationField EasyAdmin 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68519425/how-to-set-a-default-value-in-associationfield-easyadmin-3) but as mentioned in this case the request is not available to use.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out we can get the request from the request stack.

```
public function createEntity(string $entityFqcn)
{
    /** @var AgentAccreditation $entity */
    $entity = parent::createEntity($entityFqcn);

    $request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();

    if ($agentId = $request->query->get('agentId')) {
        $agentRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Agent::class);
        $agent = $agentRepository->find($agentId);
        $entity->setAgent($agent);
    }

    return $entity;
}
```

}